# How will the end season playoffs work for 2020-21 season?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, schedule

Usually, the end of season playoffs are top 8 from each conference, but since this year, because of the pandemic, there's the North division and not really a east vs west conference, how will the end of season playoffs work?

I would guess the top 4 of every division, but then which divisions are paired on the same side? I can't seem to find an official plan for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2020-2021 season's [playoffs format](https://www.nhl.com/news/nhl-teams-in-new-divisions-for-2020-21-season/c-319844882) is gonna be unique given the circumstances. The top 4 team in each division make it to the playoffs, where they play against each other based on rankings. That is 1st team against the 4th, 2nd vs the 3rd. There are no wild card teams this year.

The divisional rounds are played till there are 4 teams left, the 4 division winners. These 4 teams will then play each other based on regular season points again, till the Stanley Cup champion is determined. All series are best of 7.

Comment: OK so they will do a 1v4/2v3 for each division, then when they got all 4 winners they will check the NHL general standings and recreate a 1v4/2v3 setup.

Comment: yes, that's exactly right

Comment: Guess we will hear soon if they plan to do bubbles again or not. But thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if they bubble the last 4 teams. As there will be a Canadian team and there will be border issue.